# How to get the first and the last record of every month within a time range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the first record and the last record of each and every month in a given date range using sql. I have  a sample code where i have just selected everything within the date range now i have to extract the first and the last records of each and every month.

```
SELECT  PurOrderNum,
        OrderDate
FROM    Purchasing.PurOrder
WHERE   OrderDate >= '2013-02-28'
        AND OrderDate <= '2014-12-29'
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: My bad, yes i am using sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try row_number():

```
WITH FilterOrders AS (
    SELECT
    *
    , MinDatePrio = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate) ORDER BY OrderDate, PurOrderNum)
    , MaxDatePrio = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate) ORDER BY OrderDate DESC, PurOrderNum DESC)
    FROM Purchasing.PurOrder
    WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '2013-02-28' AND '2014-12-29'
) SELECT PurOrderNum, OrderDate FROM FilterOrders
WHERE MinDatePrio = 1 OR MaxDatePrio = 1
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: On point Jarle. I just replaced * with PurOrderNum, OrderDate and I got what I wanted. thank you man